# Unable to read undefined 'map' property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After clicking the button called gameIp functions, I download a set of questions and answers from the database, e.g.

```
    state = {
    qBank: {
    Correct: "Tomek"
    Question 1: "What is your name?"
    RouteId: 1
    Answers: ["ala", "ola", "Tomek", "jan"]
    }
    }
```

Which assigns to some name "if (id === point.RouteId)"
The problem is the error that pops up in the Uncaught TypeError version: The undefined "map" property cannot be read. I can't deal with this problem. Request for experienced programmers to peek where I'm making a mistake?

```
gameIp(id) {
        const newQuestion2 = []
        for (const point of this.state.qBank) {
            if (id === point.RouteId) {
                newQuestion2.push({
                    question: point.Question1,
                    answers: [...point.Answers],
                    correct: point.Correct,
                    id: point.Id
                });

            }

        }

        this.setState({ qBank: newQuestion2 })
    }
```

In the render method I display to:

```
    {this.state.qBank.map(({ question, answers, correct, id }) => (
    <QuestionBox key={id} question={question} options={answers} selected={answer => this.computeAnswer(answer, correct)} />
                                    )
                                )}
```

QuestionBox looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const QuestionBox = ({ question, options, selected }) => {
    const [answers, setAnswer] = useState(options);
    return (
        <div className="questionBox">
            <div className="question">{question}</div>
            {answers.map((text, id) => (
                <button key={id} className="answerBtn" onClick={() => {
                    setAnswer([text]);
                    selected(text)
                }}>{text}</button>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
export default QuestionBox;
```

Comment: there's two `.map` in the code - which one is causing the error?

Comment: The above error occurred in the <QuestionBox> component:

Comment: so `answers` is undefined ... if you do `(answers || []).map((text, id) => {` does the error go away?

Comment: yes, strange :O

Comment: Since you're new, keep in mind that you should try to use a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The less code you can use to reproduce the same problem, the easier it is for others to help you. :)

Comment: perhaps the code in `const QuestionBox` is being executed before `gameIp` has had a chance to set state - however, my knowledge of reactjs is extremely limited so I'm only speculating